# Add to browser history without page reload

Tags: javascript, url, browser, back, browser-history

Basically, I have a page that contains a form. When a user submits that form, a Javscript function is called and the user is dynamically presented with a new form.

At this point, what I would like is for the user to be able to click the browser's back button and be taken back to the first form. Is this possible?

---

Thanks for the quick responses, but I am having trouble getting pushState to work. The HTML still displays "second form" after I click the back button.

Here is the code I used to test it:

```
<script>
function newPage(){
    history.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1");
    document.getElementById('formBox').innerHTML="second form";
}
</script>


<input type="button" onclick="newPage();" value="forward" />
<div id='formBox'>first form</div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

Relevant [link to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Comment: This is fine if you don't mind it breaking in older browsers.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson (but mostly for future developers who find this answer) such functionality Should be treated at present as a nice addition to make a better user experience.  The inconvenience of not having the back option doesn't break the site and fallbacks can be implement such as the `beforeunload` event.  As browsers move forward this should be the correct answer because it is native javascript.

Comment: I know it came from the docs the same way you've written it, but do you know what effect the stateObj has? What is the purpose of foo: and "bar"?

Comment: @Luke the `stateObj` can contain whatever you want it to. When you use `history.back()`, `history.forward()`, or `history.go(target)` (where `target` is either an integer or a full/partial url), or if the user uses the browser's back button, then you can access that `stateObj`. E.g. `window.onpopstate = function(event) { alert(JSON.stringify(event.state));` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: Elliot, I think you also need to add @Buttle's comment to your answer. Both of them together helped me out.

Answer (score 15):

I've accomplished similar behaviour with the HTML5 History/State APIs, using [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/), described thus:

> Provide a cross-compatible experience for all HTML5 Browsers (they all
>   implement the HTML5 History API a little bit differently causing
>   different behaviours and sometimes bugs - History.js fixes this
>   ensuring the experience is as expected / the same / great throughout
>   the HTML5 browsers)

Example:

```
History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1");
```

Comment: This is native JS functionality, no need for a library.

Comment: Agree, but historyjs is pretty handy

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, but I am bit confused about how exactly to restore the original form after the back button is clicked. When I hit "back" it stays on the page, but the second form still remains.

Comment: You store whatever data you like in the first argument, an `object` to the `History.pushState` function. In your code that handles state changes, you need to use this information to restore the page to its previous state manually.