# AngularJS: How to clear query parameters in the URL?

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS application needs to have access to the user's LinkedIn profile. In order to do that I need to redirect the user to a LinkedIn URL which contains a callback redirect_uri parameter which will tell LinkedIn to redirect the user back to my webapp and include a "code" query param in the URL. It's a traditional Oauth 2.0 flow.

Everything works great except that LinkedIn redirects the user back to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/?code=XXX&state=YYY#/users/123/providers/LinkedIn/social-sites
```

I would like to remove `?code=XXX&state=YYY` from the URL in order to make it clean. The user does not need to see the query parameters I received from LinkedIn redirect.

I tried `$location.absUrl($location.path() + $location.hash()).replace()`, but it keep the query params in the URL.

I am also unable to extract the query parameters, e.g. "code", using `($location.search()).code`.
It seems like having ? before # in the URL above is tricking Angular.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I ended up getting the answer from AngularJS forum. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/R4FsdeYtSaQ/S1LO-fCj284J) for details

---

The link is to a Google Groups thread, which is difficult to read and doesn't provide a clear answer.  To remove URL parameters use

```
$location.url($location.path());
```

Comment: I think you meant to put the path in $location.url() instead of $location.path. Trying to merge them both like above does not work for me.

Comment: does not work for me too. Both functions leave the query param there.

Comment: helpful answer indeed. In my scenario, each time after the first time I had trigger $location.path('/reportmaint').search({<myparams> }), it never cleaned out the previous query parameters.

Comment: this causes a back button loop in chrome as in the back button goes back to //example.com?key=value, but angular forwards to //example.com. Suggestions?

Comment: +1 for `The link is to a Google Groups thread, which is difficult to read and doesn't provide a clear answer`

Answer (score 157):

I use

```
$location.search('key', null)
```

As this not only deletes my key but removes it from the visibility on the URL.

Comment: this causes a back button loop in chrome as in the back button goes back to //example.com?key=value, but angular forwards to //example.com.  Suggestions?

Comment: This sounds a bit like code issue to me. Angular should not forward anything, unless there's some king of method added by you. Also, adding .replace() replaces current history entry.

Comment: viewModelHelper.navigateTo('foo/'); was persisting the query string to the foo url, so i fixed it by using window.location.href = 'foo/'; instead.

Comment: Do not use window, use Angular's $window instead. It will be easier to unit test. More: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: This anwers works perfect if you want to delete an especific param, thanks.

Comment: This is much better as it is not accessing private variables. The way Angular is intended.

Comment: @Julius or alternatively, you could expect your developers to know the bare minimum about how javascript works and not copy paste crap internet code into your project. That is my preferred method for making sure window doesn't get overridden.... $window as a service is a prime example of overly complicating something very simple in a useless and annoying way.

Answer (score 81):

To remove **ALL** query parameters, do:

```
$location.search({});
```

To remove **ONE** particular query parameter, do:

```
$location.search('myQueryParam', null);
```

Comment: Works for Angular 1.5 as well.

Comment: also works with `undefined`, in case you're avoiding using `null` like I am.

Comment: What i do not like is if you go back with the browser back button, you loose the search query i did just before in my previous search page.

Comment: @Gino As a work-around, you can add a record to the browser history before this reset. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10541388/586051

Comment: @RahulDesai I'm using ng-route, i tough it will do it automatically

Comment: This only worked for me if I also added `reloadOnSearch:false` in the route (Angular 1.5).

Answer (score 29):

To clear an item delete it and call $$compose

```
    if ($location.$$search.yourKey) {
        delete $location.$$search.yourKey;
        $location.$$compose();
    }
```

derived from angularjs source : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c77b2bcca36cf199478b8fb651972a1f650f646b/src/ng/location.js#L419-L443

Comment: brilliant! Worked like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me, but I would assume Julius' solution is  more correct, as it seems to be what Angular guys had in mind when they created the `search` method. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search

Comment: Thanks, this worked quite well... Interestingly, IE8 likes to set/compose that URL and then load it subsequently. I'm sure this is why proper routing is preferred and also why we are all bad people. :P

Comment: Also keep in mind that any methods/variables prefixed with `$$` are *not* considered PUBLIC APIs in AngularJS—and therefore can be subject to change/break from release to release without notice. While AngularJS is now in LTS mode and unlikely to receive anything but security patches in the near future, it's still a good reason in general to avoid using these interfaces wherever possible, because they're considered "internal" implementation details.

Answer (score 27):

You can delete a specific query parameter by using:

```
delete $location.$$search.nameOfParameter;
```

Or you can clear all the query params by setting search to an empty object:

```
$location.$$search = {};
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this solution doesn't work well while switching over pages (the parameters can reappear, even if `$location.$$search = {}` is executed). @basarat solution is working well.

Comment: Worked fine for me - maybe check the sequence in which you are removing the parameter and changing path?

Comment: Although this may work it accesses private variables which shouldn't be modified, see @Julius answer for another solution

Answer (score 27):

At the time of writing, and as previously mentioned by @Bosh, `html5mode` must be `true` in order to be able to set `$location.search()` and have it be reflected back into the window’s visual URL.

See [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1521](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1521) for more info.

But **if** `html5mode` **is `true`** you can easily clear the URL’s query string with:

```
$location.search('');
```

or

```
$location.search({});
```

This will also alter the window’s visual URL.

(Tested in AngularJS version `1.3.0-rc.1` with `html5Mode(true)`.)

Answer (score 12):

### Need to make it work when `html5mode` = `false`?

All of the other answers work only when Angular's `html5mode` is `true`. If you're working outside of `html5mode`, then `$location` refers only to the "fake" location that lives in your hash -- and so `$location.search` can't see/edit/fix the actual page's search params.

Here's a workaround, to be inserted in the HTML of the page *before* angular loads:

```
<script>
  if (window.location.search.match("code=")){
    var newHash = "/after-auth" + window.location.search;
    if (window.history.replaceState){
      window.history.replaceState( {}, "", window.location.toString().replace(window.location.search, ""));
    }
    window.location.hash = newHash;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Another way I avoided configuring html5Mode to true is by creating the query string such that it contains the **#** right before the **?**.   so have   `myapp/#?client=clientName`    instead of    `myapp/?client=clientName`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to move to another URL and clear the query parameters just use:

```
$location.path('/my/path').search({});
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```
$location.url();
```

Instead of

```
$location.path();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using routes parameters just clear $routeParams

```
$routeParams= null;
```

Comment: This will just set the local variable `$routeParams` to `null`. Won't actually affect the URL parameters in the address bar at all.

Answer (score 1):

How about just setting the location hash to null

```
$location.hash(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you process the parameters immediately and then move to the next page, you can put a question mark on the end of the new location.

for example, if you would have done
$location.path('/nextPage');

you can do this instead:
$location.path('/nextPage?');

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the above answers but could not get them to work. The only code that worked for me was `$window.location.search = ''`

Answer (score 0):

I can replace all query parameters with this single line: `$location.search({});`
Easy to understand and easy way to clear them out.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer worked for me, but I needed to dig a little deeper to fix the problems with the back button.

What I noticed is that if I link to a page using `<a ui-sref="page({x: 1})">`, then remove the query string using `$location.search('x', null)`, I don't get an extra entry in my browser history, so the back button takes me back to where I started. Although I feel like this is wrong because I don't think that Angular should automatically remove this history entry for me, this is actually the desired behaviour for my particular use-case.

The problem is that if I link to the page using `<a href="/page/?x=1">` instead, then remove the query string in the same way, I *do* get an extra entry in my browser history, so I have to click the back button *twice* to get back to where I started. This is inconsistent behaviour, but actually this seems more correct.

I can easily fix the problem with `href` links by using `$location.search('x', null).replace()`, but then this breaks the page when you land on it via a `ui-sref` link, so this is no good.

After a lot of fiddling around, this is the fix I came up with:

In my app's `run` function I added this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
    $rootScope.locationPath = $location.path();
});
```

Then I use this code to remove the query string parameter:

```
$location.search('x', null);

if ($location.path() === $rootScope.locationPath) {
    $location.replace();
}
```