# Remove Parameters Before Hash Using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question may seem a duplicate and it can be. But I have tried the below solutions which do not seem to work:

1. $location.search('lang', null)
2. $location.url($location.path());
3. $location.$$search = {};

**Question:**

When I first redirected to my angular app Url looks like:

http://subdomain.domain.com/?lang=en-US#/UserList

As it hits my Asp.Net controller(on `BeginExecuteReady`) I process the language and set culture. And now want to remove the param and question-madrk i.e. "?lang=en-US".

And I have HTML5Mode off for the app. Some angular threads suggests its not possible as:

> changing anything but the hash without html5 history will result in a
>   browser reload.

Please guide me towards light.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible when HTML5Mode is off. This workaround might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24129356/3563439.

Answer (score 1):

```
$window.location.search = ''
```

This is the code that worked for me.