# Angularjs: How to remove querystring from url?

Tags: angularjs

I enter url `http://localhost/HTMLUS12706?key=1234` which redirects to `http://localhost/HTMLUS12706/?key=1234#/index`.

Now I need to remove ?key=1234 from url and update url to `http://localhost/HTMLUS12706/#/index`.

I have already tried these

```
        $location.search('key', null);
        $location.url($location.path());
        delete $location.$$search.key;
        $location.$$compose();
        $location.$$search = {};
        $location.search({});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to clear query parameters in the URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376416/angularjs-how-to-clear-query-parameters-in-the-url)

Comment: I have already gone through this question but nothing works.

Comment: What do you see in $location.$$search object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$location` service to get the url params. Like this,

```
$location.search().key
```

Answer (score 0):

$location has a method called url( urlString ) which sets the path to urlString.
Check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location). The same method when called without params returns the current url path.